# How to upload document with metadata to avoid duplicate versioning?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, versioning, sharepoint-api

I am upload document to document library along with metadata using server object model in sharepoint foundation 2010. I am using following code

```
// Initialize instance of existing site collection
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
                    {
                        //Initailize instance of exiting web site (for e.g. Team Site)
                        using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                        {
                            //Get list with specified name in the existing web site
                            SPList list = web.Lists[libraryName];

                            //Get the collection of folders in the existing web site
                            String url = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString();
                            SPFolderCollection folders = web.GetFolder(url).SubFolders;

                            //Add new folder in the exiting collection of folders
                            SPFolder folder = folders.Add(folderName);

                            //SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(siteUrl + "/" + libraryName + "/" + folderName);
                            //byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@fileUrl);                                                     

                            //Add file in the newly added folder with overwrite
                            var overWrite = true;
                            SPFile file = folder.Files.Add(saveFileWithName, fileContents, overWrite);


                            //Get the list item of the newly added file
                            SPListItem listItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
                            //Assign values to the fields of newly added file
                            listItem["User_x0020_Name"] = userName;
                            listItem["Document_x0020_Type"] = documentType;
                            listItem["Check_x0020_Type"] = checkType;
                            //Update the list item with the newly added values to the fields
                            listItem.Update();

                            //Get the unique id of the newly added list item
                            documentGuid = listItem["UniqueId"].ToString();

                        }
                    }
```

The above code works fine. I have versioning enabled on my document library. When the above code run it creates two versions in document library. One when it upload document with

```
SPFile file = folder.Files.Add(saveFileWithName, fileContents, overWrite);
```

and another when it adds values to the column `User_x0020_Name`, `Document_x0020_Type` and

`Check_x0020_Type` using

```
listItem.Update();
```

I want to create only only one version when user upload document as well as add metadata. How to do this ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the code same just replace *"listItem.Update();"* with ***"listItem.SystemUpdate(false);"*** it will update the metadata and will not increase the version number.